# Focus remains on field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out why my focus remains on an element. This is html from the [autocomplete](https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete) angular plug-in that I'm using:

```
<autocomplete id="search" ng-model="query" attr-placeholder="" click-activation="true" data="items" on-type="updateItems" on-select="searchItems"></autocomplete>
```

but every time I press enter no matter if I have my focus on the input field or not, or even on an other field, the on-select function is called every time.

this thing is in the plugin itself, maybe it needs some changes?

```
document.addEventListener("blur", function (e) {
    // disable suggestions on blur
    // we do a timeout to prevent hiding it before a click event is registered
    setTimeout(function () {
        scope.select();
        scope.setIndex(-1);
        scope.$apply();
    }, 150);
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor what was the last selected input field with this code :

```
var lastFocusedElement = '';

// This would catch any input field - so you could add your forms selector too.
// for example : $("#myForm:input")
$(":input").focus(function () {
     lastFocusedElement = $(this);
});
```

Then use the complete callback function from animate :

```
$("#div_NotificationOuter").animate({ bottom: '+=30px' }, 4000,function(){
  if (lastFocusedElement != ''){
    lastFocusedElement.trigger('focus');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm strange sollution, but the `on-select ` is called when I press enter in a `contenteditable="true"` div so animating that would look weird right?